# How can we decode a base64 encoded string which is zip format in Mule?

Tags: base64, mule, decode, dataweave, mulesoft

I am calling a webservice using Mule 3.8.3. the output from webservice is in the form of a base64 encoded 
string which is zip file, I need to decode and extract this zip in Mule? Is there a way to achieve this? base64 encoded string upon decoding and extracting gives pdf & xml data.

Answer (score 0):

I have just implemented a new mule app (on 3.9.2) with similar requirement: requesting the data via SOAP webservice which returns the zip file containing 1 or more PDFs base64 encoded.

I successfully extracted the zip file as follows:

```
<set-payload value="#[xpath3('//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/..../ns:file/ns:content', payload, 'STRING')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<base64-decoder-transformer xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" encoding="utf-8"/>
```